# Set Category and Full Article Image

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles, overrides, images

Joomla 3.4.4

I have a single category called 'Departments'. This contains hundreds of articles.

Is there any way I can set the same '**Full Article Image**' for each of these articles? See image;

[image]

I understand I can set an image for the 'Departments' category, and display this within the article but that's not what I require. I need all the articles to display the same Full Article Image.

If I could set the Full Article Image to be the **same** as the category image that would work.

Perhaps I am overlooking something obvious?

Comment: Go with a an alternative menu item for this specific category.

Comment: Not sure I understand @FFrewin Could you explain briefly please? Thanks. Also updated question, it's the Full Article Image I need not the intro image.

Comment: I would like to give a detailed answer, but I am currently out of time. Maybe  later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thought I'd give my 2 cents on this. I'm sure there are other ways, but this is the one I came up with and tested.

So, using a system plugin and JS, you can set a value for the full article image input.

Here is the code I've written:

```
class plgSystemMyPlugin extends JPlugin
{    
    public function onBeforeCompileHead()
    {
        $app    = JFactory::getApplication();
        $option = $app->input->get('option');
        $view   = $app->input->get('view');
        $layout = $app->input->get('layout');

        // Only execute via the backend
        if (!$app->isSite() && $option == 'com_content' && $view == 'article' && $layout == 'edit') 
        {
            $doc = JFactory::getDocument();

            $doc->addScriptDeclaration(
                "jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                     $('#jform_images_image_fulltext').val('images/powered_by.png');
                });"
            );
        }   
    }   
}
```

- It firstly checks to see if you're in the backend.
- Then it checks to see if your in the correct component, view and layout.
- Then injects jQuery into the `<head>` which changes the value of the input field.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @Lodder So, this way I simply open up the article for editing in the back-end and the JS injection does the rest?

Comment: @johnny_s - Yup, that's correct :) Oh I almost forgot to mention, you will also need to change the default image I've used for the value to whatever suits your needs ;)

Comment: @johnny_s - You're welcome. Glad it helped